# Getting keys from dict with Python and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, dictionary, pymongo

I am trying to loop through a data set and check if the data exists in my MongoDB.

I am using:

```
# Insert all venues
for venue in tree.find('Venues').findall('Venue'):

  #
  venue_id = venue.find('VenueID').text

  # Find venue
  existing_venue = db.venues.find_one({"venue_id": venue_id})

  # If exists
  if existing_venue:

    # Update existing
    print(existing_venue._id)
```

but I get the error in the line with `print(existing_venue._id)` saying `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_id'`.

If I simply print `existing_venue` (instead of `existing_venue._id`), I see that the dictionaries DO include the key `_id`, so I don't understand why this happens.

The exact same problem happens if I check for any other key that I know I have inserted.

When printing `existing_venue`, I get

```
{'_id': ObjectId('59875acef5ec4eb0c85c1aa0'), 'name': 'Empire State Building'}
```

Comment: `print(existing_venue['_id'])`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the correct way to access a key-value pair in a dictionary in python (3) is: dic['key']. Maybe you can try this (existing_venue['_id'].

for more information about a dictionary in python see:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html (5.5)